# Group of Rotations Stabilizer in D4

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

In D4, the subgroup of rotations is not a stabilizer for any point in a square (even the center). Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, I wanted to ask if the subgroup of rotations of D4 is a stabilizer for any point in a square (my answer was that it is not).

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us where this statement comes from? Shouldn't the stabiliser of the central point in the square be the entire group?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I found the stabilizer groups for all the potential points in a square as part of a homework problem, and found that, indeed, D4 is the stabilizer group of the center. However, isn't the stabilizer group of the center of the square by definition all the elements of D4 which stabilize the center, therefore making the subgroup of rotations ineligible as it lacks the reflections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Any non-center point is clearly not stabilized by any non-trivial rotation, thus its stabilizer cannot contain this subgroup. The stabilizer of the center is plainly seen to be the entire group (it is stabilized by both generators), and we are done.